# Change direction of Bootstrap Dropdown on React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to display a navbar Dropdown to open to the left, but it keeps opening to the right. My dropdown is located at the far right of the navbar and when I open it, it opens to the right, going outside of the layout.

I've already tried the "pull-right" and "pull-left" solutions to no avail. Also the "dropdown-menu-right" and "dropdown-menu-left" solutions don't work.

html5

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a className="nav-link" id="walletOptions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src={require('../img/wallet.svg')} alt="easyfeedbacktoken" height="40px" />
                </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="walletOptions">
            <ImportMnemonicModal onUpdateMnemonic = {this.props.onUpdateMnemonic}/>
            <ShowMnemonic mnemonic = {this.props.mnemonic}/>
            <DeleteWallet onUpdateMnemonic = {this.props.onUpdateMnemonic}/>
        </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I want the dropdown menu to drop to the left. It always drops to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropleft, Dropup and Dropright solutions didn't worked in my particular situation.
Neither the "pull-right" or "pull-left" solution.

I was able to force the Dropdown to drop into a specific coordinates using the following solution:

```
.nav .dropdown{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 88%;
  top: 30%;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute !important;
  left: -8em;
  top: 3em;
}
```

Making the dropdown button be in a specific position and the dropdown menu drop exactly how I wanted it to.
For Smaller devices, I just used @media and put another set of rules in order for the dropdown menu to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from a dropDOWN to a dropLEFT.
That way it always opens to the left

Change :

```
<li className="nav-item dropdown">
```

To :

```
<li className="nav-item dropleft">
```

Complete code :

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li className="nav-item dropleft">
            <a className="nav-link" id="walletOptions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src={require('../img/wallet.svg')} alt="easyfeedbacktoken" height="40px" />
            </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="walletOptions">
        <ImportMnemonicModal onUpdateMnemonic = {this.props.onUpdateMnemonic}/>
        <ShowMnemonic mnemonic = {this.props.mnemonic}/>
        <DeleteWallet onUpdateMnemonic = {this.props.onUpdateMnemonic}/>
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Source bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropleft-variation)